# No App working after system update to version 5.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have Lenovo A2010-a  I  updated to latest system version 5.1.  after updating all  App  have stopped working , Message " unfortunately 'name of  App'  has stopped" appears repeatedly. Even system default App  like  Google  Play Service is  not  working  and  above  message pops-up.  I reset app preferences  , force stopped App, rebooted but nothing is solving problem